How to get values from sub-arrays and put them into new arrays?
I have a text like "foo 1, bar 2, baz 3" in cell C1.
I want to separate this into 2 arrays:
["foo", "bar", "baz"] and [1, 2, 3]
I currently have this formula:
=LAMBDA(x;TEXTSPLIT(x; " ";;TRUE))(TEXTSPLIT(C1; ","))

My Idea was, I pass the array ["foo 1", "bar 2", "baz 3"] into the lambda so I can further split every item inside the lambda function. However, in excel this is not possible.
It only returns the array ["foo", "bar", "baz"] and if I try to use Index function get the second item, I only get errors.
Is there another way to get this result, without VBA?

Many ways to output. One doesn't needs a LAMBDA() here!

You could try one of the followings:


• Formula used in cell C3 :
=TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",",",1)

Or,
• Formula used in cell C7
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",",",1))


Or, 

=TOROW(TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",", ",1),,1)


Also, using LAMBDA() could try:
=LAMBDA(α,TOROW(TEXTSPLIT(α," ",", ",1),,1))(C1)


If you want to define the delimiters then,
=LAMBDA(α,δ,φ,TOROW(TEXTSPLIT(α,δ,φ,1),,1))(C1," ",", ")



Thanks! This is really helpful. One more thing; I want to have the two arrays in different locations so how do I split up the array from the TOROW function to only have [foo, bar, baz] or to only have [1, 2, 3]?

@user2740769 TOROW() is not needed since you said, you want to have both side by side so i assumed. To have any one of it, can use =LET(a, TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",",",1), TAKE(a,,1)) for the first one and for the second use : =LET(a, TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",",",1), TAKE(a,,-1))

@user2740769 or just : =TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",",",1),,1) and =TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",",",1),,-1) or =DROP(TEXTSPLIT(C1," ",",",1),,1) or =TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(C1,", ")," ") and =TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(C1,", ")," ")

@user2740769 hope you are able to understand.

Thank you, I learned so many new excel functions today

Glad to know that. Have a wonderful day ahead!
